# Basic question about Chi-Square goodness of fit test

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

i am given a sequence of 20 random numbers.

.05,.15,.23,.18,.06,.27,.31,.36,.32,.45,.55,.56,.51,.67,.62,.83,.96,.90,.70,.77.

All in the interval [0,1)
And now i am supposed to check, if those numbers satisfy the chi-square goodness of fit test for uniformly distributed random numbers. The significance level alpha = 0.05.

If i just use the formula, do not seperate those numbers into intervals, i get a result of 3,2892 which is way smaller, than the 16,92 i get out of the table.

But ... am i not supposed to check intervals? like on a sample size of 100, or even 500, with expected numbers and so on? Is this task just a cheap trick and can not be done?

If it can be done, how? I am quite lost on that one.

Comment: It is impossible to apply test without separating numbers by intervals. The chi-squared test is a test for groupped datas. For 20 numbers in a sample you can use three or at most four equal intervals.

Comment: That is what i thought. It still bothers me a bit, that the intervals are not given. I might try it with 3 and 4 intervals, all being equal. Thanks.